# Regular expression Hashtag

Tags: java, regex

My regex to find a hashtag is:

```
String REG_EX_TAG = "[#]{1}+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\b";
Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.compile(REG_EX_TAG);
```

but if I insert the string `today it's a beautiful sunny day #sun. Hello my name is Mat #Sweet#Home` the result is:
the tag `#Sweet,#Home,#sun`

I would rather that the result was only the tag #Sweet and #sun

How can I change my regex?

Comment: `javascript` `java` what?

Comment: difference in one or another

Comment: Pretty sure you meant java...

Comment: the problem is the regex not the language

Comment: @Matteo Regex for JS is not same as for Java Regex !

Comment: Will the string contain **only** hashtags? If so, can one hashtag have multiple words separated by underscores?

Comment: No the string contain a text and hashtag

Comment: Use `String REG_EX_TAG = "#[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\b";` and then call `.find()` only once (if you use `while`, replace with `if`)

Comment: @Matteo I've edited my answer three times, and you keep updating your question. Please clarify: Will the desired tags (the ones you want have) be preceded by any non-space characters?

Comment: @Matteo Therefore, the tags you want, will they exist like a separate word i.e. after a space?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoderI am not an expert of regular expressions. It's hard for me to explain myself better. My problem is that when the tag is made up this way (in the form of a text, the result must be #sun and #Sweet.

Comment: @Matteo I apologize then, I simply wish to know whether the tag to be found will be present after a space :)

Comment: @Matteo Also, I've updated my answer again, hopefully, it will give you your desired output.

Comment: @Matteo Just for posterity, does my code work for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this could help:

```
".*?\\s(#\\w+).*?"
```

Implemented in your program as follows:

```
String YourString = "Today is a beautiful sunny day #sun. Hello my name is Mat #Sweet#Home";

String REG_EX_TAG = ".*?\\s(#\\w+).*?";

Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.compile(REG_EX_TAG);
Matcher m = tagMatcher.matcher(YourString);
if(m.find())
{
    String tag = m.group(1);
    // Whatever you want to do with the tag - store it, print it, etc.
}
```

`m.group(1)` contains the tag (because in the regex, it is enclosed within parentheses)

## Regex -

`^` symbolizes the very start of the String, so that the tag matched is the very first one.

`.*?` is a lazy match for any sequence of characters (the non-hashtag part) i.e. words, digits, spaces etc.

`\\s` tells the regex to match the tag with a space before it (As far as I can see, this is the condition set by the OP)

`(#\\w+)` is the actual tag, indicated by a `#` and one-or-more Word Characters i.e. letters, digits, underscores, or a combination of them.

Finally, `.*?` indicates that there may be some more text after the hashtag.

**Note -** This regex will match the typical conventions of a hashtag i.e. `#Blessed` or `#9_11` or `#I_Need_MoreUpvotes`, without any special characters, and preceded by a space.

*EDIT -* To match all tags, just replace the `if(m.find())` with `while(m.find())`

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that I have to have all the tags inserted in the text. the regex not work :-(

Comment: @Matteo Well then, just replace the if() with a while() loop. I'll edit the post in a sec.

Comment: @Matteo I've edited the post, see the bottom text for it :)

Comment: @Matteo In response to your comment on Wiktor's answer, I have once again updated my answer.

Comment: for me to fetch all the tags from sentence was to use reg-ex `(#[a-zA-z]{3,})` for input `This is a #Test example which has #somecrucial #input #trends.` should print `[ #Test, #somecrucial, #input, #trends,  ]` where 3 is min length of hashtags i support

Answer (score 2):

The `"\b"` matches a backspace char, not a word boundary. You need to double escape it.

Also, the pattern only seems to match any hashtag anywhere in a string. You need to get the first one if there is a chain of hashtags.

You may use

```
(#[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)(?:#[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6svcmC/1).

**Details**

- `(#[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)` - Group 1 capturing the first occurrence of `#` followed with 1+ letters, digits, `-` or `_`
- `(?:#[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)*` - matches 0+ repetitions of the hashtag pattern.

Grab Group 1 values only.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/IeVfwq):

```
String s = "today it's a beautiful sunny day #sun. Hello my name is Mat #Sweet#Home";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(#[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)(?:#[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)*\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
} 
// => [#sun, #Sweet]
```

Note that `{1}+` is redundant, it matches 1 occurrence of the quantified subpattern (and that is a default action).

Comment: if the text is: "today it's a beautiful sunny day #sun. Hello my name is Mat #Sweet#Home"

the result that I expect is: [#sun,#Sweet]